# fancybox 2 image refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have a fancybox 2 on my webpage which shows an image automatically generated from a webcam at full size.

I refresh the image on the webpage using the following:

```
    //reload the images so they are always current
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval('reloadBackscatterImage()', 60000); // 60 seconds
});

function reloadBackscatterImage() {
    var src = $('#backscatter-img').attr('src');
    // check for existing ? and remove if found 
    var queryPos = src.indexOf('?');
    if (queryPos != -1) {
        src = src.substring(0, queryPos);
    }
    //generate a timestamp so we always get the latest image (break browser cache)
    var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
    $('#backscatter-img').attr('src', src + "?time=" + timestamp);
    $('#backscatter-link').attr('href', src + "?time=" + timestamp);


    return false; 
}
```

and the fancybox is currently initiated by:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
       $(".fancybox").fancybox();
   });

   $("#backscatter-link").fancybox({
       openEffect: 'elastic',
       closeEffect: 'elastic',

       helpers: {
           title: {
               type: 'inside'
           }
       }
   });
```

I need the image inside the fancybox to also refresh at the same time. How can I acheive this?

Comment: do you mean that if fancybox is opened it should refresh the image inside? or if the link (`href`) is refreshed, then fancybox should open the proper image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found that the following refreshes the image without closing and reopening the fancybox:

```
        if ($.fancybox.isOpened) {
        $(".fancybox-inner").find("img").attr('src', src + "?time=" + timestamp);
    }
```

which in my opinion works better than using the click event handler.

Answer (score 0):

**First**, your fancybox initialization should be inside the `$(document).ready()` like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".fancybox").fancybox();

   $("#backscatter-link").fancybox({
       openEffect: 'elastic',
       closeEffect: 'elastic',
       helpers: {
           title: {
               type: 'inside'
           }
       }
   }); // fancybox
}); // ready
```

(this way you are binding fancybox to the element with `id="backscatter-link"` AND to all elements with `class="fancybox"`)

**Second**, if you reload the image on the web page (and change its `href` attribute) with fancybox v2.x you don't have to do anything since it will always open the corresponding image (v2.x uses the `.live()` method)

**Third**, if fancybox is already opened and the image in the webpage is refreshed (its `href` attribute has also changed) AND you want fancybox to refresh its content accordingly, then you need to add a listener within your `reloadBackscatterImage()` function to evaluate the status of fancybox and trigger a `click` to the `#backscatter-link` selector, which will open fancybox using the current `href` of such selector ... something like this:

```
 if($.fancybox.isOpened){
  $("#backscatter-link").trigger("click");
 }
```

To make this explanation clearer I create a [DEMO HERE](http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/refreshFancyboxContent_20jul12.html) that refreshes an image int the webpage every 10 seconds (I also added a fancybox status indicator.) Fancybox will always open the current image on the page when you click on it and will refresh its content accordingly.

**NOTE** : this is for fancybox v2.0.6+

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this does indeed refresh the picture as I need, however I dont like the way that it closes and reopens the fancybox. The reason for this is that there is no way of telling whether the image has actually changed and would look anoying to the user. Is there any way of just replacing the picture without the fancybox closing and reopening?

Comment: There is not way to do it the way you want unless you open an external page via `iframe` type and do that inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to solve the same problem - forwarding images from the webcam into the Fancybox.

I solved that using two Fancybox href's to the same image - same group (rel = "something"), set autoplay to true and slideshow timeout to the desired refresh interval. Works perfectly.

It starts a slideshow of 2 (virtual) images running again and again pointing to the same webcam source image.